# What exactly is a Module and what exactly is the point of Modularity?

Tags: oop, module

So there is this "modular" paradigm which (depending on the perspective) goes even above OOP itself. You can write an un-modular OOP piece of software, so to speak. I have read the wikipedia article of course and the "Objects as modules" chapter of the stairways book (its about Scala, by Martin Odersky), I also read the modules section of the wikipedia's LM article,  but I still can't get a clear understanding of what exactly is it that a modular design provides.

I think I understand the reason behind it in an abstract form: it provides a kind of separation of concern that is orthogonal to the partitioning mechanisms of the underlying language and even the programming paradigm (say OOP). But I don't quite get how exactly this is achieved. What is it about modules that is not captured by the classes, interfaces or libraries? I feel like I'm missing some big-picture, architectural point here.

Disclaimer: perhaps here is not the right place or perhaps the question itself is vague or even philosophical in nature.

Comment: How do you call a group of classes working together to achieve some objective?

Comment: @MikeSW A namespace I suppose? But on second thought, I'm beginning to get your question ...